# Multiple ascx (user controls) that use the same server side code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linqdatasource

I currently have multiple user controls in a default page. Each one has a different grid that is going to become a dashboard. However to cut down on repeating code, some of the controls use the same datasource. Is there anyway to have them all share the same datasource. Or if necessary all use the same `OnSelecting` statement that I could define elsewhere?

Such as one of the `LinqDataSources` selects all the users in a group, this displays them all in a `gridview`. However a detailed `gridview` below that in a separate ascx control uses the same data, but displays it in another way, grouping differently etc. However they both (if placed on one page) use the same datasource. If there anyway for them to use the same selecting `Sub` somehow? Maybe part of a class somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after further research into alternate ways I've decided to place my select on the default page:

```
Public Function returnGroup() As List(Of Group)
    'Use standard LINQ to SQL function to get list of what is needed
End Function
```

This has been used in combination with the `Structure`:

```
Structure Group
    Public Property Title As String : Public Property GroupID As Integer
    Public Property GroupCode As String 
End Structure
```

So when combined it creates:

```
Public Function returnGroup() As List(Of Group)
    'Use standard LINQ to SQL function to get list of what is needed
    Return LINQToSQL_Select.Select(Function(chX) New Group With {.Title = chX.Title} '... etc
End Function
```

This is then called in the `ascx` page:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVAl sender as object, ByVal e as eventargs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim cDef as New _Default
    gvGroup.DataSource = cDef.returnGroup() : gvGroup.DataBind()
End Sub
```